# SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Please find the below query. When I run this query I am getting an ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error. I am unable to understand the problem on this query. Please give me the solution for this error. I have read some related topics on this topic. but, I didn't get the right solution. I am using Oracle 10g version.

The query:

```
SELECT A.City||'.' AS AAddress,
    M_InOut_Header_v.Org_Location_ID AS Org_Location_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.ContactName, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Title, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.EMail, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Phone, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.BPGreeting, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Name2, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Name, 
    B.City||'.' AS BAddress, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.C_Location_ID AS C_Location_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.BPContactGreeting,
    --M_InOut_Header_v.BPGreeting,
    --M_InOut_Header_v.Name,
    --M_InOut_Header_v.Name2, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Address1, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Address2, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Address3, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Address4, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.City, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.POSTAL1, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.CountryName, 
    --M_InOut_Header_v.BPContactGreeting, 
    --M_InOut_Header_v.Name, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.OrderRemarks, 
    (SELECT NVL(C_Order.DocumentNo,'')||'
      - '||NVL(TRIM(TO_CHAR(C_Order.DateOrdered,'DD/MM/YYYY')),'') 
        FROM C_Order 
        WHERE M_InOut_Header_v.C_Order_ID=C_Order.C_Order_ID
    ) AS CC_Order_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.C_Order_ID AS C_Order_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.OrderType, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.ReferenceNo, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.POReference, 
    (SELECT NVL(M_Warehouse.Name,'') 
        FROM M_Warehouse 
        WHERE M_InOut_Header_v.M_Warehouse_ID=M_Warehouse.M_Warehouse_ID
    ) AS DM_Warehouse_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.M_Warehouse_ID AS M_Warehouse_ID, 
    (SELECT NVL(M_Shipper.Name,'') 
        FROM M_Shipper 
        WHERE M_InOut_Header_v.M_Shipper_ID=M_Shipper.M_Shipper_ID
    ) AS EM_Shipper_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.M_Shipper_ID AS M_Shipper_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Vehicle_No_BizInt, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.TrackingNo, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Permit_No_BizInt, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.LR_Number_BizInt, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.FREIGHTCOSTRULE2, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.FreightAmt, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.POREMARKS, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.NoPackages,
    M_InOut_Header_v.Gross_Weight_BizInt, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.UOMSymbol, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.SalesRepPhone, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.SalesRepEmail, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.DocumentType, 
    InOut_Header_v.DocumentNo, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.MovementDate, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.Description, 
    (SELECT NVL(M_InOut.DocumentNo,'')||'
      - '||NVL(TRIM(TO_CHAR(M_InOut.MovementDate,'DD/MM/YYYY')),'') 
        FROM M_InOut 
        WHERE M_InOut_Header_v.M_InOut_ID=M_InOut.M_InOut_ID
    ) AS FM_InOut_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.M_InOut_ID AS M_InOut_ID, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.DocumentTypeNote, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.REMARKS1, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.REMARKS2, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.REMARKS3, 
    M_InOut_Header_v.REMARKS4 
FROM M_InOut_Header_v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN C_Location A 
ON (M_InOut_Header_v.Org_Location_ID=A.C_Location_ID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN C_Location B 
ON (M_InOut_Header_v.C_Location_ID=B.C_Location_ID) 
WHERE (M_InOut_Header_v.M_InOut_ID=1002241) 
    AND M_InOut_Header_v.AD_Client_ID IN (1000008,0) 
    AND M_InOut_Header_v.AD_Org_ID IN (1000099,1000098,0,1000100,1000096,1000097) 
    AND (A.C_Location_ID IS NULL 
            OR A.C_Location_ID NOT IN ( 
                SELECT PA.Record_ID FROM AD_Private_Access AS PA 
                WHERE PA.AD_Table_ID = 162 AND PA.AD_User_ID <> 1013144 
                AND PA.IsActive = 'Y' 
            )) 
    AND ( B.C_Location_ID IS NULL 
            OR B.C_Location_ID NOT IN ( 
                SELECT ADP.Record_ID FROM AD_Private_Access AS ADP 
                WHERE ADP.AD_Table_ID = 162 AND ADP.AD_User_ID <> 1013144 
                AND ADP.IsActive = 'Y' 
            ))
ORDER BY M_InOut_Header_v.DocumentNo;
```

This gives me:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 80 Column: 26
```

But I didn't find any mistake in that line. I think it is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 5):

The line number is slightly misleading, but it's pointing to the start of the problem. The issue is with these two subqueries:

```
                    SELECT PA.Record_ID FROM AD_Private_Access AS PA 
                    WHERE PA.AD_Table_ID = 162 AND PA.AD_User_ID <> 1013144 
                    AND PA.IsActive = 'Y'
```

and:

```
                    SELECT ADP.Record_ID FROM AD_Private_Access AS ADP 
                    WHERE ADP.AD_Table_ID = 162 AND ADP.AD_User_ID <> 1013144 
                    AND ADP.IsActive = 'Y'
```

You cannot use `AS` to mark [an alias for a table name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55303), only [(optionally) for a column name or expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55280). There isn't actually a missing parenthesis. It's hard to know exactly what the parser is thinking, but in this case it looks like it's trying to interpret the `AS PA` as a column alias for that subquery, and that implies that the subquery should have ended by now, and so there should have been a close parenthesis already. (Another option might have been to try to treat `AS` *as the table alias*, but then it would have had to try to decide what `PA` meant; plus `AS` is a keyword so it wouldn't be valid as an alias name anyway).

Just remove the `AS` keyword from both of those and it'll work (or move on to another error).

```
                    SELECT PA.Record_ID FROM AD_Private_Access PA 
                    ...
```

and:

```
                    SELECT ADP.Record_ID FROM AD_Private_Access ADP 
                    ...
```